# Small angles tangent approximation

Tags: trigonometry

Please ignore my scribbles.

From the picture we can say:

$$\frac{1}{2}r^2\sin\theta < \frac{1}{2}r^2\theta <\frac{1}{2}r^2\tan \theta$$

When we divide out the inequalities we get:

$$\sin \theta < \theta < \tan \theta$$

Now if we divide be $\sin \theta$ we can indeed show that for small positive $\theta$ as $\theta$ approaches zero, $\frac{\theta}{\sin \theta}$ approaches $1$.

Now the book states that the same analysis can be performed for $\frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}$ by simply dividing out the inequalities by $\tan \theta$. And I am not finding this understandable:

$$\cos \theta < \frac{\theta}{\tan \theta} < 1$$

As $\theta$ approaches zero, $\cos \theta$ approaches 1 but at the same time $\frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}$ is less than $1$, because that is what the rightmost part of the inequality shows... ? So how can $\frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}$ be 1 is it has to be less than 1? I suppose it is because $\frac{\theta}{\tan \theta}$ is approximately 1 in the limit and not not 1?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the limit, strict inequalities may become weak inequalities. For instance

$$\frac{1}{n}>0 $$

for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$, while

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \geq 0 $$

(with an equality in fact).

**EDIT:**

To elaborate, another way of writing the above is

$$\frac{1}{n} \in (0, \infty)\quad \forall n. $$

However, since the set $S:=(0,\infty)$ isn't closed, the limits of some sequences in it might 'escape'. The smallest *closed* set that contains $S$, aka the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) $\overline{S}$ of $S$ definitely contains all such limits of sequences in $S$. In our case $\overline{S}=[0,\infty)$.

Comment: So you are saying that the rightmost part of that inequality becomes $\leq$? Why is this the case, generally? I.e. That strict inequalities become weak? I can see why it is the case in the above example. But not why it is the case in mine.

Comment: In the case of $\theta\over\sin\theta$ you have ${\theta\over\sin\theta}>1$ but the limit is $1$. So what?

Comment: I didn't see that haha! Exactly! So what? That is my question. And the answer is above. Now I am trying to understand when the inequality exactly becomes weak

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Edited. Hope this addresses your concerns.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that as $n$ becomes arbitrarily large, $g(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ is never ever ever ever equal to zero. Similarly, $f(\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$ is always larger than one and is never ever ever ever equal to one. Understand that a limit is a boundary, but not necessarily a member of the domain of a function.